# React Native and Redux: How to create unique route key for navigation?

Tags: ios, react-native, redux, reactjs

In React Native/Redux project, I have a side menu with navigation buttons to navigate to `<Home/>` or `<Profile/>`. If either is clicked on for the FIRST time, for example `Home` button, then it navigates successfully to `<Home/>`.

And if I click on `Profile` button, it navigates to `<Profile/>`, but if I click no the `Home` button again to navigate to `<Home/>`, I get the following error:

[image]

So how can I PUSH with unique key every time using Using, NavigationStateUtils? Or is there a better approach to handling unique key?

Looked around everywhere and tested for days but no luck, so came here looking for some help!

**Here is the code**

navReducer.js:

```
const initialState = {
  index: 0,
  key: 'root',
  routes: [{
   key: 'login',
   title: 'Login',
   component: Login,
   direction: 'horizontal',
  }]
}

function navigationState (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case PUSH_ROUTE:
      if (state.routes[state.index].key === (action.route && action.route.key)) return state
    return NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.route)

    case POP_ROUTE:
      if (state.index === 0 || state.routes.length === 1) return state
      return NavigationStateUtils.pop(state)

   default:
     return state

  }
}
```

Methods that handle navigation and used `Home` route for example:

```
  _handleNavigate(action) {
    switch (action && action.type) {
      case 'push':
        this.props.pushRoute(action.route)
      default:
        return false
    }
  }

const route = {
  group: {
    type: 'push',
    route: {
      key: 'home',
      title: 'Home',
      component: Home,
      direction: 'horizontal',
    },
  }
}

this._handleNavigate(route)
```

**EDIT**

Is this how you are supposed to make the route push for the button?

```
const route = {
  interest: {
    type: 'push',
    route: {
      key: 'profile',
      title: 'Profile',
      component: Profile,
      direction: 'horizontal',
      unique: true,
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case, basically you will need to jump between these specific routes once they have been pushed. Everytime pushing Login or Home, Navigator expects it to be new route. But your navigation stack already have Home and Login route. NavigationStateUtils have jumpTo method for this.

Before calling push, check whether route already exists in stack and make jumpto call it is in stack already. You can change your navigationState something like following:

```
function navigationState (state = initialState, action) {
 if(action.type == PUSH_ROUTE && action.route.unique==true)
 {
    if(state.routes.find(child => child.key === key))
    {
       return NavigationStateUtils.jumpTo(state, action.route.key)
    }
 }
 switch(action.type) {
    case PUSH_ROUTE:
      if (state.routes[state.index].key === (action.route && action.route.key)) return state
    return NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.route)

    case POP_ROUTE:
      if (state.index === 0 || state.routes.length === 1) return state
      return NavigationStateUtils.pop(state)

    default:
     return state

  }
}
```

Routes can be like following:

```
const initialState = {
  index: 0,
  key: 'root',
  routes: [{
   key: 'login',
   title: 'Login',
   component: Login,
   unique:true,
   direction: 'horizontal',
  }]
}
```

Also I think your following if statement will ever be true :

```
if (state.routes[state.index].key === (action.route && action.route.key)) return state
```

Comment: thank you for the response but before accepting the answer and upvote, is there a way to make it so that it not only checks for 'home' but all routes?

Comment: You can set some flag in route info. Like unique. so if action.route.unique == true then make a jump.

Comment: Sorry but could you clarify flag? Or show example would really help seeing

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try by the end of tonight and let you know

Comment: Please take a look at the original post with EDIT. I made the attempt to push like so but now getting an error even if clicked on for the first time around: `key is not defined`. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Checking in to see if you've seen my last comment. Please let me know. Thank you